# Getting imu_data from jackal in simulation

Tags: ros, imu, jackal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using the Jackal robot from Clearpath. I am running the jackal_gazebo simulation and trying to collect odometry and IMU data. I have written code which has the following:

- publisher, to publish messages to "jackal_velocity_controller/cmd_vel" topic.
- subscriber which subscribes to "jackal_velocity_controller/odom" topic for odometry data and uses a callback function to read from "nav_msgs"
- subscriber which subscribes to "imu_data" topic for imu data and uses a callback to read from "sensors"

The publisher and subscribers connect to the same node. The odometry data is available and gets written into a file.
The velocity commands are visible when I do: "rostopic echo /jackal_velocity_controller/cmd_vel"
**The imu data, however, is not coming through.**
The code has the jackal moving in a straight line with a linear velocity of 2.0 in the 'x' direction. The other values, including, angular are zeros.

I expected some IMU data to come through in simulation even if the given angular velocity was zero.
Am I subscribing to the wrong topic? How can I get the imu data from the jackal in simulation?

Thanks and regards,
rsmitha.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257935/getting-imu_data-from-jackal-in-simulation/) by [rsmitha](https://answers.ros.org/users/28985/rsmitha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2017-03-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The topic is `imu/data` not `imu_data`.

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2017-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0